# How can I run all junit tests in a package and below (recursively) by right clicking the package on eclipse and selecting "Run as JUnit test"

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I found similar questions but no satisfactory answers. In addition, most answers were rather old as well, so I wonder if the combination eclipse / Junit got better in the meantime.

Instead of packing projects into test suites, I would like to spread tests cases all over the place in the package structure (I'm programming in Java). Then right clicking on whatever package (on the package explorer) should bring the option Run As -> JUnit Test and run all the unit tests in that package and below (recursively). In this way, I wouldn't have to care about maintaining the test structure, it would be in the packages themselves.

I've seen that this works only with end packages (with no children), but not recursively. Do you have any ideas? I'm using eclipse Kepler (4.3.0), JUnit 4 and Java 1.6.

Comment: Packages are not tree structure in Java, even if some IDEs can present them as "folders" (Eclipse does not by default). What you want would be hackish and a bad idea; it is not supported and that is a good thing. Create test suites.

Answer (score -1):

Why cant you create a run config in eclipse to run all the JUnit tests ? 
Refer the screen shot. 
Select the radio button which says

```
Run All tests in the selected project, package or source folder.
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to have some sort of tree structure with the tests. With your solution I can only run either all tests in the project or at the end nodes. I want to do it like this because they need several minutes to run and sometimes I would like to concentrate on just a subset. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you do want to run tests in a package only then this would suffice but if you do want to run tests from different packages then this wouldn't work with what i suggested